# Put $row into array for echoing

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I'm fairly new to PHP. I need to put $row2 into an array so I can echo each value on one cell only. I need to get separate values. Any leads would be great

```
 $diag = " SELECT walkindetails.IntID, intervention.IntName FROM walkindetails  INNER JOIN intervention on walkindetails.IntID = intervention.IntID  WHERE TID = '1'";

              $diagarray = mysqli_query($conn, $diag);
              $intarray = array();

              if ($conn->error) {
                die("Query failed: " . $conn->error);
              }
               while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($diagarray)) {
              $intarray[$index] = $row2;
              $index++;

                         ?>
                          <?php echo  $intarray[0][IntName];   ?>
                        </td> <?php

        }
        ?>
```

Comment: You don't need to put something into an array to echo it. Can you _show_ an _example_ of the output you're trying to produce?

Comment: @Don'tPanic column book, author. I have books with multiple author. the Book's ID is link to different authors but same FK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

- where you print your code, you need to use `$index` not just 0(0 would always reference the first element of the array).
- `IntName` is the key of an element, and since it's a string, it must be in quotes.
- You do not have an opening `<td>` tag in your while loop.
- You do not really need `$intarray`. Bellow is your code so it works and beneath that is a version of the while loop without the `$intarray`.

  ```
  $diag = " SELECT walkindetails.IntID, intervention.IntName FROM walkindetails  INNER JOIN intervention on walkindetails.IntID = intervention.IntID  WHERE TID = '1'";

            $diagarray = mysqli_query($conn, $diag);
            $intarray = array();

            if ($conn->error) {
              die("Query failed: " . $conn->error);
            }
            while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($diagarray)) {
                $intarray[$index] = $row2;
                $index++;

                ?>
                <td>
                <?php echo  $intarray[$index]["IntName"];   ?>
                </td> <?php

      }
      ?>
  ```

Here's version without `$intarray`

```
         <?php
         while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($diagarray)) { ?>
             <td><?php echo $row2["IntName"]; ?></td>
         <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Hi I tried your code without $intarray but now it's an array how can I echo the 1st and second value. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question. The code in this loop prints "IntName" for each row in your database. What do you refer to as the "1st" and second value?

Comment: My $row2["IntName"]; has multiple values and I'm not gonna echo it per row. I wanna echo all values into one cell only. is that possible

Comment: take the `<td>` and `</td>` outside of the `while` loop(so they are enclosing it) and the loop will loop through all `$row2["IntName"]` and put them in the same cell.

Comment: Thank you so much!